# Is there a way to address multiple apps on nginx without DNS?

Tags: nginx, dns, ip

I bought a dedicated virtual server on hetzner so now I got an IP address for it. I'm a rookie in server and DNS stuff so I'm sure I got some fundamental misunderstandings in domain.
For the moment I've got one rails-unicorn app running on the server. I have not bought any Domain name yet therefore it can be accessed just by my IP.
I want to deploy one more app to this server and I don't understand how can it be done (or how to distinguish requests for nginx so it can redirect to requested app). I suppose there two ways: redirect to different upstreams based on ports: e.g. user hit in browser 99.99.99.99:3000 and get one app and for 99.99.99.99:80 get another.
And the second way to "subdomain" my IP: user hit 99.99.99.99/app1 or 99.99.99.99/app2 and get diff apps

Am I wrong about that alternatives? If I am, what is the right answer? thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for your own testing, for the mean time until you buy the domain, i would suggest editing the hosts file (of your own pc/laptop) and adding the domain names, tricking you own pc (only) to think that this domain actually exists
the path in windows is `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
in linux it's `/etc/hosts`

and just add a record like

```
99.99.99.99 mydomain.com
```

The other method of 99.99.99.99/app1 would work too, but it's not really a subdomain, it's a subdirectory, in nginx they will all be contained inside 1 single `server { }`

Also you could use a service like `dyndns.org` and assign a host to your server (it's a free service, you don't need to pay for the offers you'll find on the site)